# How to make a parent page for a custom taxonomy in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, code-snippets, custom-taxonomy

I am using Woof product filter plugin and want to add a new taxonomy. Right now I have it set up with categories (type of products), brands using Perfect Brands for Woocommerce (assigns custom "brand" taxonomy that I add to each product to assign its brand), and I use tags for what is in each product such as ingredient 1, ingredient 2, etc.). I want to add a custom taxonomy for benefits of each product. But I also need to have a custom taxonomy called "Benefits" that will show up in the Woof product filter just like categories, tags, and brands show up so that users can filter by these things meaning they might want a category of product that is a specific brand and has a specific benefit and I need them to be able to filter that way. Right now they can filter that way just the benefits taxonomy is not there yet. What is the easiest way for me to add this taxonomy, be able to filter it for product filtering, and be able to add this benefit or multiple of the benefits to each product on the back end? Preferably with a code snippet or snippets and not needing another plugin (if at all possible). Any help is greatly appreciated!!

I am using the below code snippet and everything seems good except when you are on the solution/benefit page such as Energy the bread crumbs shows Home/Shop by Solution/Energy. But I want there to be a parent page called Shop by Solution that is clickable in the breadcrumbs and that I can add all of the solutions to like you would categories so if they go to /shop-by-solution/ it shows all solutions like energy, focus, sleep, etc. Then keep the url structure as it is now like /shop-by-solution/energy/ . How do I make it so the shop by solution in the bread crumbs is clickable and brings the user to /shop-by-solution/

Code Snippet -

```
// Register Custom Taxonomy
function ess_custom_taxonomy_Benefits() {
$labels = array(
'name' => 'Shop by Solution',
'singular_name' => 'Solution',
'menu_name' => 'Solutions',
'all_items' => 'All Benefits',
'parent_item' => 'Parent Benefit',
'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Benefit:',
'new_item_name' => 'New Benefit Name',
'add_new_item' => 'Add New Benefit',
'edit_item' => 'Edit Benefit',
'update_item' => 'Update Benefit',
'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separate Benefit with commas',
'search_items' => 'Search Benefits',
'add_or_remove_items' => 'Add or remove Benefits',
'choose_from_most_used' => 'Choose from the most used Benefits',
);
$args = array(
'labels' => $labels,
'hierarchical' => false,
'public' => true,
'show_ui' => true,
'show_admin_column' => true,
'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
'show_tagcloud' => true,
);
register_taxonomy( 'shop-by-solution', 'product', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'ess_custom_taxonomy_benefits', 0 );
```

I was told by one person to add

'rewrite'                    => array( 'slug' => 'shop-by-solution'),

But that doesn't work either

I have also tried flushing the permalinks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: To clarify, I want to make a page with slug of /shop-by-solution/ as the parent page for all of the benefits such as energy, sleep, etc. I have the code working showing the custom taxonomy and in the breadcrumbs it shows Shop By Solution but it's not clickable. I want it clickable as the parent page